# ActiveRecord Create (not !) Throwing Exception on Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, exception, activerecord

So I'm using ActiveRecord model validations to validate a form in a RESTful application.

I have a create action that does:

```
@association = Association.new
```

and the receiving end of the form creates a data hash of attributes from the form parameters to save to the database using:

```
@association = user.associations.create(data)
```

I want to simply render the create action if validation fails.  The problem is that the .create (not !) method is throwing an exception in cases where the model validation fails.  Example:

```
validates_format_of :url,         :with => /(^$)|(^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(([0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?$)/ix, :message => "Your url doesn't seem valid."
```

in the model produces:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: Validation failed: Url Your url doesn't seem valid.
```

I thought .create! is supposed throw an exception whereas .create is not.

Am I missing something here?

Ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 173 & rails 2.3.3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Read the documentation of [create](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#M001265) and [create!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M001406) carefully.

Both [create](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#M001265) and [create!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M001406) check the callbacks (in your case validations).
 [create](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#M001265) method return false if exception is raised and true if not while,
 [create!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M001406) method raised exception if the record is invalid.

However, [create](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#M001265) **can** throw an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` if you have a unique index in the database and no validation set on the model. In this case, you should add `validates :fieldname, uniqueness: true` onto the model.

Comment: How does one go about determining the false return of create when it's throwing exceptions? Does one have to handle the exception merely to find out that validation failed?

Comment: not entirely correct, `.create` can throw ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique if you have a unique index and no validation